# How to run JMeter server as a service in windows

Tags: windows, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-plugins

Is it possible to run JMeter server as a service in windows?

Currently I'm just logging in and running it manually, but from time to time I have to restart this machine and I would like to make JMeter server run automatically after each restart (even no user logs in after restart).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. To create windows service `sc create serviceName binpath= "path\to\exe"`
2. You can also create a shortcut/bat file in the windows startup folder to start the JMeter. `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`

You can also have a look at  [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748841.aspx)  - to start a program using windows task scheduler w/o user log in.